# sed search and replace item within double quotes

Tags: regex, sed

I need to use only sed to search a text file and replace a number which may be a different value.

Here is the line I need to modify.

```
"Value1": "60",
```

I know I can do:

sed -i 's/"60"/"70"/' file.txt

but this too likely to find other items in the file and does not allow me to change it regardless of the value.

What I want to do is to replace whatever the value is inside of the second double quotes after the "Value1" match.

I know this can be done, but I'm just not getting the syntax correct.

Comment: Is your input a JSON file? If so, use [tag:jq].

Answer (score 0):

The command in the other answer would also replace a value after e. g. `"Value2":`. Presumably you rather want this:

```
sed -i 's/"Value1": ".*"/"Value1": "70"/' file.txt
```

Comment: This version of code works great for my purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try it on gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/("Value1":\s*")60(",)/\170\2' file.txt

                          ^        ^
```

change the two pointed out number, 1st is which you search for and 2nd is by which you replace it